# Using 1D Perlin Noise to Generate 2D Terrain

Tags: swift, gamekit, noise, perlin-noise, noise-generator

Alright, so I'm working with Swift, and I have GameKit's GKNoise class which allows me to get a noise value given an input. If you graph it you get that standard perlin noise mountain. What I need to do is create a second perlin noise function that takes 3 inputs instead of one. I tried multiplying the inputs, and outputs, but none of them matched up the way the regular 2D cloud looked.

What I'm given (pseudo code)

```
var value = noise(input)
```

What I need

```
var value = customNoise([input1, input2])
```

What I've tried

```
var value = noise(input1) * noise(input2)
var value = noise(input1 * input2)
var value = noise(input1 + input2)
// etc
```

All I need is a way to combine noise, but multiplying it creates weird checkered patters I dislike

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using GKNoiseMap for this and it worked great, although I did have to shift some code to work with the limited playing field.